# Django model for voting system and follow feature

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, vote

I work on the voting system (vote up and vote down) and the functionality - follow.
I want it to be done well, because I don't have anyone to advise, I put the post and code here.

Follow function - it should show how many followers there are and who they are. I used here a m2m relation with the intermediate model Follower.
My question - is this the correct approach to the topic - using m2m with an intermediate model here?

Functionality vote up and vote down - it is supposed to show how many votes up and how many down and who voted down and who voted up.
My question is whether there is also OK here with the relation between m2m and the intermediate model Voter?

Code for follow feature:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Follower', blank=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def number_of_followers(self):
        return self.followers.count()


class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Code for vote up and vote down feature:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vote_up = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Voter', blank=True)
    vote_down = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Voter', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('qa:qa_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

class Voter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Now is working only follow feature but I want to make sure my approch is ok. Please and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is nothing that differentiates the up_vote from the down_vote on the Question model so this will return the same query.

As a side note if you plan to add similar voting/following functionality to other models it may be worth considering whether this is a good use case for a Generic Relationship. This will create a polymorphic relationship and is DRY.

Here are the docs
[generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Comment: I am trying avoid Generic Relation